# Python sympy Evaluating When Asked Not To

Tags: python, sympy

This works as expected:

```
>>> from sympy.parsing.sympy_parser import parse_expr 
>>> parse_expr("2**3"), parse_expr("2**3", evaluate=False)
(8, 2**3)
```

This, however, not:

```
>>> from sympy.parsing.sympy_parser import parse_expr
>>> parse_expr("sqrt(9)"), parse_expr("sqrt(9)", evaluate=False)
(3, 3)
```

I would expect:

```
(3, sqrt(9))
```

Any ideas, why?

Comment: This topic seems to have been addressed meanwhile. Using SymPy 1.11.1 the result for `parse_expr("sqrt(9)", evaluate=False)` is `sqrt(9)`.

Answer (score 3):

The evaluate flag to parse_expr only affects the direct evaluation of the expression. `sqrt(x)` is short for `x**Rational(1, 2)`, which isn't part of the expression parsing.

You can use the `with evaluate(False)` decorator to prevent the power in the `sqrt` function from evaluating:

```
>>> with evaluate(False):
...     print(parse_expr('sqrt(9)', evaluate=False))
sqrt(9)
>>>
```

(I kept the `evaluate=False` flag, but it's probably not actually needed)

Comment: I have something similar, mine is trying to keep the brackets from eavluating but none of the methods seem to be working. I have tried both the above and evaluate=False

Answer (score 2):

`evaluate=False` only guarantees that

> the order of the arguments will remain as they were in the
>   string and automatic simplification that would normally occur is
>   suppressed. (see examples).

It doesn't prevent functions from being executed.

[--Documentation](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/parsing.html)

`evaluate` only refers to operators, not to functions.

Comment: Any ideas how to prevent functions from being executed?